# Restrict output by range in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am creating an XSLT and i want to select a particular node, only if one of its child element's value is between a range. The range is to be specified using parameters in the xsl file.

The XML file is like

```
<root>
 <org>
  <name>foo</name>
  <chief>100</chief>
 </org>
 <org parent="foo">
  <name>foo2</name>
  <chief>106</chief>
 </org>
</root>
```

The XSLT so far is

```
<xsl:param name="fromRange">99</xsl:param>
<xsl:param name="toRange">105</xsl:param>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="orgo">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//org[not(@parent)]"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to restrict the org node from being processed whose < chief > node's value is not in range

Comment: i also want the restriction that the node should not have a parent attribute along with the range

Comment: Good question again (+1). See my answer for two complete solutions: XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0 :)

Answer (score 3):

> I want to select a particular node,
>   only if one of its child element's
>   value is between a range. The range is
>   to be specified using parameters in
>   the xsl file.
>
> I also want the restriction that the
>   node should not have a `paren`t
>   attribute along with the range

**Use this expression as the value of the `select` attribute of `<xsl:apply-templates>`:**

```
org[not(@parent) and chief >= $fromRange and not(chief > $toRange)]
```

**In XSLT 2.0 it is legal to have variables/parameters in the match pattern**.

Therefore, one could write:

```
<xsl:template match=
  "org[@parent or not(chief >= $fromRange ) or chief > $toRange]"/>
```

thus effectively excluding all such `org` elements from processing.

**Then the template matching the document node is simply**:

```
<xsl:template match="/">            
    <orgo>            
        <xsl:apply-templates/>            
    </orgo>            
</xsl:template>
```

This is better than the XSLT 1.0 solution, because it is more "push-style".

Answer (score 0):

```
//org[chief &lt; $fromRange and not(@parent)]
    |//org[chief > $toRange and not(@parent)]
```

This expression will exclude all nodes that are in the range specified by `fromRange` and `toRange`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="fromRange">99</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="toRange">105</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="orgo">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//org[chief &lt; $fromRange and not(@parent)]|//org[chief > $toRange and not(@parent)]"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think OP wants in range nodes.